# instrA is faster than instrB on CPU but vice versa on GPU?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

Is there an example that:

```
on CPU, Instruction A is faster than Instruction B
However, 
on GPU, Instruction B is faster than Instruction A
(Instructions are assumed to be math operations)
```

This may be due to some factors of GPU like:

- GPU executes data-dependent instructions in parallel, which could be worse than sequential execution
- High cache miss rate, bank conflicts

Comment: Just because two platforms have a similarly named instruction, which maybe even does just about the same thing, doesn't have to mean that both will behave exactly the same.

Comment: Is this your homework? It is way more complex than A vs. B.

Comment: No, not my homework. I am learning for my own interest

Comment: Everything is slower per core in gpu. There are many cores in gpu and good local memory space/registers.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, for a long time it was pretty common for GPUs to not have native support for 32b integer arithmetic (especially multiplication).  There are lots of CPU / GPU combinations where a 32b integer multiply is faster than a 32b floating-point multiply on CPU, and vice-versa on GPU.

Comment: One mentioned that NxM matrix math is faster on CPU for large N and M, whereas GPU is good at dealing with small NxM matrix.